# Add Row number (Serial Number) in datagridview in last column

Tags: c#

In Datagridview i want serial number or row number for that i am using below code in RowPostPaint method

```
'private void dataGridView1_RowPostPaint(object sender, DataGridViewRowPostPaintEventArgs e)
    {
        this.dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells["SlNo"].Value = (e.RowIndex + 1).ToString();
    }'
```

i am getting serial number or row number i first column but i want it at last column of my datagridview so how to do it.
please help me

thanks

Comment: Is it winforms? you can change the cells place via the designer

Comment: @ofir Winegarten i got the solution thanks